# multiple filters in angular view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I have this

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in (filteredNumber =  (phones | filter : 'jason Raq'))">
```

this works fine and show me the name json Raq as filtered result but now I need two names . Jason and Mark

I tried this to get it working but no success

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in (filteredNumber =  (phones | filter : {'jason Raq':'Mark'}))">
```

I also tried

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in (filteredNumber =  (phones | filter : 'jason Raq' | filter :'Mark'))">
```

but no luck...how do we do multiple filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in (filteredNumber = (phones | filter : 'jason Raq').concat((phones | filter : 'Mark')))">
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/F7liEAy72irlvy1CS8KO?p=preview)

This works but it seems that you misunderstand the concept of angular filter.

The filter value is used to match with elements that satisfy the value.

In your code, it's like that you want to specifies **multiple values** and use an **OR** condition to match any elements satisfying one of the values.

If you need to do something like that, you have to write your custom filter. Like this:

```
app.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(input, filterValues) {
      var out = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
         if (filterValues.indexOf(input[i]) >= 0){
           out.push(input[i]);
         }
      }

      return out;
    }
  });
```

Use it:

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in (filteredNumber = (phones | customFilter : ['jason Raq','Mark']))">
```

Or:

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones | customFilter : ['jason Raq','Mark']">
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6YNLwXlNTtHKtKPXN3u6?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a controller function to get `filteredNumber` like this

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter : filterByName">
   <span ng-bind="phone.name"></span>
</li>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.filterByName= function(phone){
   return (phone.name === 'jason Raq') || (phone.name === 'Mark');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hGF3Kv7a02ztsrM5lpMw?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try puting the names on an array and then filter `phones` based in that array:

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in (filteredNumber =  (phones | filter : ['jason Raq','Mark'])">
```